# Create a hard link from a file handle on Unix?

Tags: linux, macos, unix

If I've got a handle to an open file, is it possible to create a hard link to that file after all references to it have been removed from the filesystem?

For example, something like this:

```
fd = fopen("/tmp/foo", "w");
unlink("/tmp/foo");
fwrite(fd, "Hello, world!\n");
create_link_from_fd(fd, "/tmp/hello");
fclose(fd);
```

Specifically, I'd like to do this so that I can safely write to large data files, then move them into place atomically without having to worry about cleaning up after myself if my program is killed in the middle of writing the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not generally, no.  [**Edit**: since Linux 3.11 there is now `linkat`; see [safsaf32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18644492/1256452).  This does not work on POSIX systems in general since POSIX `linkat` is restricted to directories only.]  There are security considerations here: someone can pass to you an open file descriptor that you could not normally `open` on your own, e.g.:

```
mkdir lock; chmod 700 lock
echo secret contents > lock/in
sudoish cmd < lock/in
```

Here `cmd` runs as a user who has no permission to `open` the input file (`lock/in`) by name, but can still read from it.  If `cmd` could create a new name on the same file system, it could pass the file contents on to a later process.  (Obviously it can copy those contents, so this issue is more of a "pass the contents on by mistake" thing than "pass the contents on, on purpose".)

That said, people have come up with ways of "relinking" files by inode/vnode internally (it's pretty easy to do inside most file systems), so you could make your own private system call for it.  The descriptor must refer to a real file on the appropriate mount point, of course—there's no way of "relinking" a pipe or socket or device into becoming a regular file.

Otherwise you're stuck with "catch signals and clean up and hope for the best", or a similar trick, "fork off a subprocess, run it, and if it succeeds/fails, take appropriate move/clean-up action".

---

Edit to add historical note: the above `lock` example is not particularly good, but back in the days of V6 Unix, [MDQS](http://ftp.arl.army.mil/~mike/papers/82usenix-mdqs/usenix.html) used a fancier version of this trick.  Bits and pieces of MDQS survive in various forms today.

Answer (score 14):

The newly released linux 3.11 offers a solution to this problem with the new `O_TMPFILE` `open(2)` flag. With this flag you can create an "invisible" file (i.e. an inode with no hardlinks) in some file system (specified by a directory in that file system). Then, after the file is fully set up, you can create a hardlink using `linkat`. It works like this:

```
fd = open("/tmp", O_TMPFILE | O_RDWR, 0600);
// write something to the file here
// fchown()/fchmod() it
linkat(fd, "", AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/test", AT_EMPTY_PATH);
```

Note that aside from the >=3.11 kernel requirement, this also requires support from the underlying file system (I tried the above snippet on ext3 and it worked, but it did not seem to work on btrfs).

Comment: That this works, or using `/proc/self/fd/n`, is substantiated by http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.file-systems/76553

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you might try the unportable trick of using `/proc/self/fd` by trying to call

```
 char pbuf[64];
 snprintf (pbuf, sizeof(pbuf), "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
 link(pbuf, "/tmp/hello");
```

I would be surprised if that trick worked after an `unlink("/tmp/foo")` ... I did not try that.

A more portable (but less robust) way would be to generate a "unique temporary path" perhaps like

```
 int p = (int) getpid();
 int t = (int) time(0);
 int r = (int) random();
 sprintf(pbuf, sizeof(pbuf), "/tmp/out-p%d-r%d-t%d.tmp", p, r, t);
 int fd = open  (pbuf, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY);
```

Once the file has been written and closed, you `rename(2)` it to some more sensible path. You could use `atexit` in your program to do the renaming (or the removing).

And have some `cron` job to clean the [old] `/tmp/out*.tmp` every hour...

Comment: To avoid security problems never use such a scheme to generate a "unique and temporary path", instead use the POSIX `mkstemp`(3) call to create a unique name and open it in one call.

Comment: Also note that the temporary file should be created in the future target directory, not inside `/tmp` or some other random location. This is because otherwise the file may be on wrong filesystem and moving it (ovewriting rename) to replace the existing file is no longer atomic.